# File Paths once moving to IIS

Tags: pdf, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, path, directory-structure

I'm having trouble to accessing some pdf's once I move my site to IIS. My codes in C# and I used MVC2 asp.net 3.5. 
Here's my code in the solution to open up the pdf:

`return File("~/Views/pdf/TestPDF.pdf", "application/pdf");`

Works fine when I run it from my local machine. Opens up the pdf perfectly.

We have a main website(MainWebsite) already and what I'm doing is just a side(SideWebsite) one. We're using IIS 7. The way it would work is that "www.MainWebsite.com\Side Website" would be used to access it. In IIS the MainWebsite is a site with a physical path of "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MainWebsite\" and the Side website is an Application Pool with a physical directory of "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SideWebsite\".

```
Sites
   >MainWebsite (Physical path:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MainWebsite\)
      >SideWebsite (Physical path:C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SideWebsite\)
```

Site works great getting access to it and going from page to page when going to "www.MainWebsite.com\Side Website" but when I try to open up a pdf it looks for it in "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MainWebsite\Views\pdf\TestPDF.pdf" instead of using the physical path and going to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SideWebsite\Views\pdf\TestPDF.pdf".

So whether its in my code or in IIS is there a way to have the pdf point to the SideWebsite physical path instead of the MainWebsite's physical path without going...

`return File("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/SideWebsite/Views/pdf/TestPDF.pdf", "application/pdf");`